# How can I convert an array to an object by splitting strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I have an array like below:

```
["gender-m", "age-20", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"]
```

I tried to generate a JSON object:

```
{"gender":"m", "age":"20", "city":"london", "lang":"en", "support":"home"}
```

One solution I can think of is using FOR loop to make it, but I am sure there are elegant solutions for this. Any suggestions, please help me.

Comment: could use `Array.reduce`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with the splitted key/value pairs.

```js
var data = ["gender-m", "age-20", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(s => s.split('-')));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nina, I marked it as the answer because it's the 1st respond, working and elegant way :). But the topic still welcomes the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.reduce

```
const arr = ["gender-1", "age-m", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"]
arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
    const str = c.split('-')
    return {...acc, [str[0]]: str[1]}
}, {})
```

Comment: Impressive, but nearly indecipherable. I suggest intuitive variable names and a little documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an elegant way because you use the "-" sign to separate key and value. So, the best way would be:

```
let element = {};
array.forEach(item => {
result = item.split("-"); 
element[result[0]] = result[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be solve with **split** and a map, foreach item inside of the array replace the **-** with **:** using the split it will be turned into a key value, then assign those values to the object you want to return.

```
var arrayObject = ["gender-m", "age-20", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"];
var objectResulted ={};

arrayObject.map(
  function(item){ 
  var splitedValue = item.split('-');  
  objectResulted [splitedValue[0]]= splitedValue[1] 
  });
```

console.log(objectResulted);

Answer (score 1):

Since you originally tagged this as a "Lodash" question, here is a Lodash-based answer:

```js
const arr = ["gender-m", "age-20", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"];

const obj = _.chain(arr)
  .map(v => _.split(v, '-'))
  .fromPairs()
  .value();
  
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.reduce` method

```html
["gender-m", "age-20", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"].map(s => s.split('-')).reduce((rs, el) => {rs[el[0]] = el[1]; return rs;}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` method to do that

```html
["gender-m", "age-20", "city-london", "lang-en", "support-home"].reduce((rs, el) => {rs[el.split('-')[0]] = el.split('-')[1]; return rs;}, {});
```